# Is it ok to warn someone who recites too loudly while praying?

Tags: salat, adab

From time to time I stand in line to pray (saff) beside people who are loud while we are praying. Sometimes it can be annoying when we are in *sujud* to hear other voices. Is it permissible for me to draw his attention to the fact that his voice is too loud and that he is impeding me while I pray?

Comment: If there is one thing Sunnah of prophet teaches us, it is patience. Warning; and that too for prayer related matter doesn't sound appropriate for a Muslim.

Comment: I think it is right to tell the person if it is disturbing your prayer.

Comment: I think the main concern is **timing**, whenever I notice an issue with a brother during prayer I try to tell them after saying my salams, and getting to know them. No one wants to feel judged.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is right to tell the person if it is disturbing your prayer.

This is a verse from the quran that states we should use a proper tone depending on the situation.

> Say, "Call upon Allah or call upon the Most Merciful. Whichever [name] you call - to Him belong the best names." **And do not recite [too] loudly in your prayer or [too] quietly but seek between that an [intermediate] way**. [[Surat Al-'Isrā' 17:110](http://quran.com/17/110)] (Sahih International)

So we must follow that.

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum. Brother, your answer isn't helpful. Please consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

You should warn him politely after he finishes his prayer. Don't draw his attention while he is praying. It may disturb him. Read the following fatwa for more.

> One of my friends while offering sunnah namaz recites surah in a
> little loud voice that I can easily hear his recitation and get
> disturbed in my namaz. What should I do?
>
> (Fatwa: 271/000/H=03/1437)
>
> Ask him to recite in the same volume in sunnah salah as the others do.
> If he follows it then it is ok; otherwise you should offer sunnah at a
> distance from him.
>
> [Darul Ifta, Darul Uloom Deoband](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Salah-Prayer/62933)